# Github like Source Code Browser tool for OS X

Tags: ide

I really like github's source code browser--it's fairly light weight, has syntax highlighting, etc.

Is there something similar available as a desktop app? I'm not looking for an IDE like XCode. Just a nice file explorer that is geared around code.

Bonus for supporting git.

One solution would be to just push my code to github, but I need to keep the code private. I'm looking at a desktop app,

I have SourceTree (a git gui tool), and that is more geared around Git and less about source code navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not the most optimal solution, I ended up finding a github like clone.

[Gitlab](http://gitlab.org/) is an opensource, and hosted solution similar to GitHub.

Bitnami provides VMWare virtual Appliance which you can use to quickly setup a GitLab server.

Started the VM, logged in, created a project, added gitlab as a remote, and pushed my code to the server.

I can now use my browser to navigate local source files in that project similar to github.